# Улучшение распознавания pytesseract

Tags: python, распознавание-символов

Я пытаюсь сделать распознавание отчетливого набора букв - `Arcane Adress` в рамке, но `Tesseract` не справляется.

Как улучшить качество распознавания?

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image,  ImageEnhance, ImageFilter

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract'

img = Image.open("C:\\Users\loljkpro\Desktop\DoD\AA.png").crop((804, 540, 1120, 580))
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang='eng')
print(text)
img.show()
```

[Мое изображение](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Ungaminga/loljkpro.tk/master/images/AA.png)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: С этой строкой Tesseract справился у меня без ошибок. Можете выложить картинку с которой Tesseract не справился?

Comment: У меня распознало `Curpzarlechliuufur`. Может я сделал что-то не так с самим `Tesseract `?

Comment: я использовал `tesseract 4.0.0-beta.1-108-gf291`. Какая у вас версия?

Comment: У меня не бета, а стейбл. tesseract-ocr-setup-3.05.01. Сейчас попытаюсь накатить бету.

Comment: в `Tesseract 4.0` используются рекурентные нейронные сети, использующие алгоритм `LSTM` (Long short-term memory) - один из самых эффетивных и популярных при работе с естественными текстами. В общем я бы рекомендовал перейти на `Tesseract 4.0` и соответствующие обученные модели (с использованием LSTM)

Comment: После танцев с бубном (перемещение языковых файлов) все сработало на бете. Большое спасибо. Если хотите - оформите ваши комментарии как ответ, я его заапрувлю.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как выяснилось из общения в комментариях, автор вопроса использовал `tesseract-ocr-setup-3.05.01`. В новой версии [Tesseract 4.0 with LSTM](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/4.0-with-LSTM#400-alpha-for-windows) используются рекуррентные нейронные сети, использующие алгоритм [LSTM (Long short-term memory)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C) - один из самых эффетивных и популярных при работе с естественными текстами.

[Google протестировал точность распознавания для больших объемов данных (для языка Hindi)](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/4.0-Accuracy-and-Performance):

```html
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Engine</th>
<th>Total char errors</th>
<th>Word Recall Errors</th>
<th>Word Precision Errors</th>
<th>Walltime</th>
<th>CPUtime*</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Tess 3.04</td>
<td>13.9</td>
<td>30</td>
<td>31.2</td>
<td>3.0</td>
<td>2.8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Cube</td>
<td>15.1</td>
<td>29.5</td>
<td>30.7</td>
<td>3.4</td>
<td>3.1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Tess+Cube</td>
<td>11.0</td>
<td>24.2</td>
<td>25.4</td>
<td>5.7</td>
<td>5.3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>LSTM</td>
<td>7.6</td>
<td>20.9</td>
<td>20.8</td>
<td>1.5</td>
<td>2.5</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

`Tesseract 4.0 with LSTM` показал гораздо лучшие результаты (меньше ошибок и работает быстрее) по сравнению с `Tesseract 3.04`

**Вывод:** есть смысл попробовать новую beta версию `Tesseract 4.0 with LSTM`